# what does "matrix valued function is continuous differentiable" mean?

Tags: matrix-calculus

I have a question regarding definition for matrix valued function. 
Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^q \to \mathbb{R}^q \times \mathbb{R}^d$, which is a matrix
valued function. Then what does it mean by $f$ is continuous differentiable? Where can I find reference for this kind of calculus material?

Comment: Do you know multivariable calculus? Do you know what it means for a function $f : \mathbb{R}^q \to \mathbb{R}^m$ to be continuous, to be differentiable, and to be continuously differentiable? If so, set $m=q+d$… if not, look up any multivariable calculus book.

Comment: Thanks. So you are saying we should vectorize the matrix as a long vector?  I know multivariable but single valued function, but not quite familiar with the vector valued function.

Comment: @Sean A matrix valued function would have codomain $\mathbb R^{n\times m} \simeq \mathbb R^{n\cdot m}$. Your codomain just consists of pairs of vectors, one from $\mathbb R^q$ and one from $\mathbb R^d$.